# Run R script / function declaration without repeating the contents of the code?

Tags: r, function, output

I have R file where I write code, define functions and use them.
When I run it, I see all my code in blue repeated and afterwards it runs the code.

Please advise how to avoid this behavior.

For example:

```
ped2df <- function(file) {

  df <- read.pedfile(file)
  names(df) <- df[1,]
  df <- df[-1,]
  df <- gather(df)

 }
test <- lapply(files, ped2df)

Running this:

# Get ped files and convert them into long dfs:
> 
> ped2df <- function(file) {
+   
+   df <- read.pedfile(file)
+   names(df) <- df[1,]
+   df <- df[-1,]
+   df <- gather(df)
+   
+ }
> 
> test <- lapply(files, ped2df)
```

I want it to run only `test <- lapply(files, ped2df)`.

P.S

I have tried adding `;` but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the part of the code that you want to run before clicking on run?

Comment: I have a script + function in it + run these functions + load data etc.
I need all the prerequisites to run and use the commands like the one I have shown. There is no way to do this?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't want to *see* the functions definition in the console? or is the problem that you don't want the functions definitions to be run at all?

Comment: I want the declarations/assignments/functions to run silently and show only the practical side: I have defined function foo, show me only the use of it: r <- foo(5).
I don't want to see in the output the whole function, it's also done for security and privacy.

Comment: I want the defenitions/function to be black boxed for the one who runs them. Here is a function, here is the wrapper to implement and get desired results, I don't want to you to see the function details and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use self-defined functions, but not have them displayed when you run the script you can use `source("your_self_defined_functions.R")`.

You split your `.R` file into two files:

- One in which you define the functions (save it as `"your_self_defined_functions.R"`)
- One where you only want to call the functions and do your analysis.

The latter should look something like this:

```
source("your_self_defined_functions.R")

files <- somethingsomething
test <- lapply(files, ped2df)
```

And the entire `your_self_defined_functions.R` is run silently.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I wanted to do it in one file, isn't it possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to see the function definition? Does it have something to do with Markdown?

Comment: What do you mean? I am less familiar with it.
My goal is to show relevant information/run details, I want all the declarations to run silently especially functions.

Comment: I am not aware of such a possibility. I would either do what Barbara suggested and only highlight the code you want to display in the console, or use `source()`.

Comment: Thanks Ken! You are the professional, I trust you so I will do it yours/Barbara's way.